# java debug/development mode

Tags: java

In C/C++ we can use `#ifndef RELEASE #endif` to include debug source such as some extra tests and/or console print and etc

Is there any way to do it in java or any similiar alternative ?

Comment: Doing this would be a bad hack. Logging should be done through a configurable logging mechanism with different log levels. Tests should be done in unit tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `static final boolean` variable and then use simple `if` statements.

If the compiler can determine that the expression is `false` then it will not compile the conditional into your code.

Comment: +1 I learned something cool today. Is this true for any compiler of any version ? I mean is it in the JLS

Comment: At least the Oracle/Sun Compiler do it. I don't know since which version, but at least recent compiler (> 1.4) do it.

Comment: @Jerome It is not in the JLS as it is just a compiler optimization.